# LINQ making orderbydesc generic

Tags: c#, linq

I have written the `LINQ` query as following but just wondering if i can make it more generic and get rid of the hard coded values.

```
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "DESC":
        if(sortBy == "A")
            query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Field1);
        if(sortBy == "B")
            query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Field2);
        if (sortBy == "C")
            query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Field3);
        break;
    default:
        if(sortBy == "A")
            query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Field1);
        if(sortBy == "B")
            query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Field2);
        if (sortBy == "C")
            query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Field3);
        break;
}
```

The link mentioned as duplicate is not the answer i am looking for. In that question user asked by sorting 1st of ASC and then Desc.

In my case i have to either sort ASC or DESC.

Comment: Never ever use `string`s to control execution. Use `bool` flags, `enum`s or, even better, polymorphy.

Comment: Who sets the `sortBy` variable? Is it selected by the user and passed to this code?

Answer (score 2):

You can only do that using **Reflection** i guess:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Order<T, V>(IEnumerable<T> query, string sortOrder, 
                                    Func<T, V> fieldSelector)
{
    string methodName = sortOrder == "DESC" ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                                          .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(methodName))
                                          .FirstOrDefault();

    MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Resource), typeof(V));

    var orderedResults = (IEnumerable<T>)genericMethod.Invoke(null, 
                                    new object[] { query, fieldSelector });

    return orderedResults;
}
```

Usage:

```
var orderdResults = Order(query, "DESC", x => x.CategoryId).ToList();
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting such that we can read it without scrolling vertically. Also this wont work for `IQueryable`s, i.e. it won't work with Entity Framework. `fieldSelector` should be an `Expression<Func<T, V>>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you would want to reimplement LINQ's `OrderBy()`, but this is the most sensible way to do it, I guess:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> Order<TSource, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
        Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, 
        bool descending = false)
    {
        return descending 
            ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
            : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }   
}
```

You'd use it like the standard `OrderBy()`, i.e. you give it an expression that selects a property of `TSource`:

```
var newest = query.Order(x => x.Id, true).First();
var oldest = query.Order(x => x.Id).First();
```

Workinge example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TcEEqY